# "Expected string or bytes-like object" using re.match() against a tuple

Tags: python

I don't have anyone who's coding in my area i'd love if someone can help!

I'm using vs code

```
import re

data = ('bat', 'bit', 'but','gdt', 'hat', 'hit', 'hut', 'hdg', 'grt')
patt = (r'[bh][aiu]t')

res = re.match('patt', data)

res.group()

res.groups()
```

I need to match pattern to bat,bet,bit,hut. However, I get these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\David Amsalem\Desktop\Tech\python\core python appliction programing\exercise\chapter 1\01\script.py", line 6, in <module>
    res = re.match('patt', data)
  File "C:\Users\David Amsalem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\re.py", line 173, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: A title should specify your specific question, in enough detail that someone else can tell if they had the same problem. I've tried to edit towards that end.

Comment: you can't search an iterable like that, you can perform your search for each item in your tuple using a `for loop`

Comment: `data` is a tuple, but python is expecting to match a String. you would have to loop through `data` with a `for` loop. Also, you are trying to match with the regex `"patt"` instead of the variable `patt` that you defined, which is also a tuple.

Comment: Try take patt out of quotation marks in your re.match

Comment: @Sirsmorgasboard that's incorrect....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The re.match function works on a single string. But you can filter a list or tuple of strings like this:

```
import re

data = ('bat', 'bit', 'but','gdt', 'hat', 'hit', 'hut', 'hdg', 'grt')
patt = r'[bh][aiu]t'
r = re.compile(patt)

print(list(filter(r.match, data)))
```

gives you:

```
['bat', 'bit', 'but', 'hat', 'hit', 'hut']
```

Comment: I'd suggest removing the excess parens around the `patt` definition, if trying to demonstrate better practices than what the OP did.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: good suggestion. I took the code from the question, but you are right.